# Non varargs call of a varargs method

Tags: android

This is my sample code where I am getting the warning.
The compiler says:

```
non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to Class<?> for a varargs call
cast to Class<?>[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
```

or
display an error like

```
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/LoaderManagerImpl;
```

Kindly help please..

Comment: Hi, I fixed your typos and formatting. You should do that yourself next time. Pay attention to the error message, it's "varargs", not "vargas". Please go ahead and [edit] your question and add the code that produces this error, as a [mcve]. The other error seems unrelated, and you may need to open a new question for that; it's only one topic per question here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Note that spelling / typing errors actually matter.  Many people locate relevant Q&As by searching using Google or StackOverflow search.  It you misspell words, they are much less likely to show up in search results.  Hence, your Q is less likely to come to the attention to the people who can answer it, and is less likely to be useful to other people.   (Now there are helpful people who will correct spelling errors, etc.  But there are not *enough* people, so may errors never get corrected.)